Project Laravel Error Failed to open stream: No such file or directory and File Permission
I have a Laravel project, but when I installed it on another laptop it didn't work, an error appeared when the environment was changed to Development, the error is as below.
Even though my previous laptop was normal.
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: include_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\talent-crm\application\hooks/libraries/App_modules.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: hooks/InitModules.php

Line Number: 12

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\talent-crm\application\hooks\InitModules.php
Line: 12
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\talent-crm\application\hooks\InitModules.php
Line: 12
Function: include_once

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\talent-crm\index.php
Line: 319
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: include_once(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\talent-crm\application\hooks/libraries/App_modules.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Filename: hooks/InitModules.php

Line Number: 12

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\talent-crm\application\hooks\InitModules.php
Line: 12
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\talent-crm\application\hooks\InitModules.php
Line: 12
Function: include_once

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\talent-crm\index.php
Line: 319
Function: require_once

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Class "App_modules" not found

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\talent-crm\application\hooks\InitModules.php

Line Number: 17

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\talent-crm\index.php
Line: 319
Function: require_once

What's the solution? Is the missing setting on the laptop XAMPP?
the php versions are both 8.2

You might need to run composer install in terminal to install all dependencies. Or if you have copied your project without making a zip file then it might also has not copied all files.

Please check the project path in the .env file, and provide the exact project path

"when I installed it on another laptop" - how did you do that? "an error appeared when the environment was changed to Development" - do you mean it worked on the new laptop before you made this change? Does it work again if you change back to whatever it was before?

Note that XAMPP is not the best option for a Laravel app. Did you install the app using git/composer or did you just copy the files including the vendor dir?

@GertB. I did both, first I cloned from Github and I immediately copied everything via Google Drive. The result is the same. Error.

@Don'tPanic What I mean is, I did development on laptop A and it ran normally, but when I Clone or Copy on laptop B, an error like the one above appeared.

This error is because InitModules.php, which was previously in your project, is now not found.
A few points:

Search for the InitModules.php file on the first computer where
the program was running correctly and add it to the file you placed on the second computer.
Composer must be installed on the second computer and you must
have executed the composer install command in the program.
If your program has a database, you must have done the settings
in mysql
Be sure to check that the .env file is in your project so that
everything works properly

